# Why is Google Chrome Unresponsive on Windows 11?

Tags: windows, google-chrome, windows-update

Yesterday (2023-02-09), Chrome became excessively sluggish.  It took 2+ minutes for the app to load.  Google search results were quick, but it took minutes to load a page that took a fraction of a second in Edge.

I tried disabling all extensions, clearing all cache, running in incognito mode, restarting Windows, deleting my Chrome app data and uninstalling and reinstalling Chrome (without logging into Chrome), clearing temp files in app data, but nothing worked.

Answer (score 0):

I finally tracked down the problem to Windows Updates.

I ran Chrome again this morning (2023-02-10) and found it still extremely slow.  I installed the recommended Windows Updates, then re-ran Chrome.  Chrome became responsive again.

The windows updates that were installed that seem to have fixed the issue are:

- Windows Malicious Software Removal Tool x64 - v5.106 (KB890830)
- 2023-01 .NET 6.0.13 Security Update for x64 Client (KB5022546)
- Intel Corporation - SoftwareComponent - 2.17.100.2
- 2022-12 .NET Core 3.1.32 Security Update for x64 Client (KB5021953)
- 2022-12 Cumulative Update for .NET Framework 3.5, 4.8 and 4.8.1 for Windows 10 Version 22H2 for x64 (KB5021089)

I'm not sure which combination of these updates fixed the problem, but I hope to limit others' frustration with this problem.